# Python Function Functionality

Tags: python, function, python-3.6

I am venturing into the wonderful world of Python! Python3, to be exact. Well, Python 3.6 to be more exact? Anyway, I am learning about functions in Python and I decided to write a function in Python the way I know how to write a function, and it worked! However, I've never seen a Python function written this way, in the documentation, in books, or in random examples on the internet.

So, let's take something small, like getting a "player name".

In C++, it would be something like:

```
string getPlayerName(string playerName) {
    output << "What is the name?";
    input >> playerName;

    return playerName;
}
```

Naturally, there would be another function (or not ;) ) to displayPlayerName or showPlayerName, but you would have to initialize the function variables:

```
void displayPlayerName() {
    string playerNameFunction = "";
    string playerNamePlaceHolder = "";

    playerNameFunction = getPlayerName(playerNamePlaceHolder);

    output << "Hello, " << playerNameFunction << "!" << endl;
}
```

Now, in Python, I've not seen anything like this. I've seen where the variables are more hard coded in all the examples I've seen.

```
def _getAge(age):
    print("How old are you?")
    print(age)

_getAge(30)
```

BUT! If we use the C++ example, that works and seems perfectly legal and logical in Python!

```
def _getPlayerName(playerName):
    playerName = input("What is the name?")

    return playerName

playerNameFunction = ""
playerNamePlaceHolder = ""

playerNameFunction = _getPlayerName(playerNamePlaceHolder)
print("Hello, " + playerNameFunction + "!")
```

Now, I know that probably looks like crap, and I know the long windiness of it all probably defeats the purpose of Python. But I'm curious to know if my methods of using functions are unconventional for Python, or if I'm just not deep enough in it to understand a more fluid way of writing the code.

Any thoughts?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your C++ function isn't good C++. There's no reason to take `playerName` as an argument; you'd just declare `string playerName` locally.

Comment: What is the point of `playerName` in `_getPlayerName(playerName):`? The code does nothing with the value that is passed. The actual logic of the function is better served by just using `getPlayerName()`, in which case `print(Hello, " + getPlayerName() + "!")` is idiomatic enough. (Using the underscore in the function name is considered bad practice).

Comment: Similarly, taking a `playerName` argument in your Python function is pointless, too.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! My recollection of CPP was not as good as I thought, apparently heh. Going to do quite a bit more research and get a better grasp on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern isn't good C++ or good Python. The `playerName` argument is pointless.

In C++, you should have written either

```
string getPlayerName() {
    string playerName;

    output << "What is the name?";
    input >> playerName;

    return playerName;
}
```

and called it as

```
string playerName = getPlayerName();
```

rather than needlessly copying a placeholder value from the caller and then overwriting it, or

```
void getPlayerName(string& playerName) {
    output << "What is the name?";
    input >> playerName;
}
```

and called it as

```
string playerName;
getPlayerName(playerName);
```

to read the player name directly into a string passed by reference.

---

In Python, you should have written

```
def getplayername():
    return input("What is the name?")
```

There is no pass-by-reference option in Python.

Comment: Interesting. Obviously I need a lot of review since I couldn't remember the cout or getline() syntax LOL.

I appreciate the feedback! I have a few books (my preferred method of learning) and when I got curious I started reviewing the actual Python documentation and some videos. Definitely going to get back into the groove of things.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could condense it down to this in Python while loosely maintaining the structure you were going for:

```
def _getPlayerName():
    return input("What is the name?")

print("Hello, {0}!".format(_getPlayerName()))
```

This could all be in one line too if you like:

```
print("Hello, {0}!".format(input("What's your name?")))
```